# Android 11 UI issues with dialog transparency

Tags: android, android-layout, android-11

did you notice any UI issues with Android OS 11(API 30).
I have a full screen transparent dialog with a progressbar at center, it is working till Android 10, don't know its showing a black dark background in Android 11. Please share if you guys have any thoughts on this issue.

This is how I am setting dialog background transparent:

```
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Comment: Did you get the solution for this?

Comment: @ramyabr you can try my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `setBackgroundDrawable()` is deprecated now that's probably why you are getting this issue. An alternative could be `setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.your_drawable)` where you can replace the drawable with your color.

Answer (score 0):

Struggling with same issue lead me to this solution;

```
    Window window = dialog.getWindow();
    window.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.argb(58, 0, 0, 0)));
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(1);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);//Set contentView after setting background drawable
    dialog.show();
```

Simple, setting the contentView after setting background drawable solved the issue. There might some other approaches like setting background as resource. This is what fit for me.

Answer (score 0):

Without further details I can only make a guess on the solution. But I believe this is an issue where `LayoutParams` are being replaced. Instead I would suggest modifying the `LayoutParams` a view/window already have.

Get the layout params:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = window.attributes;
```

Modify attributes as you like, e.g. `params.width = WRAP_CONTENT` And then set the modified layout params:

```
window.attributes = params
```

I suggest this solution to all `LayoutParams`, it usually give the best solution to more android versions. And less attributes has to be set.